# Execution of data step despite of the errors

Tags: sas

I am executing the following code to combine a large number of data sets . Here is code:

```
 %macro combine;
 data modelfit;
 set
 %do i = 30 %to 116 %by 3 ;
  stat&i
   %end;
    ;
 %end;
 run;
%mend;
%combine;
```

However, few of the data sets are not present. Hence, the data set is failing to execute. How can I prevent the data step from stopping to execute and combine the data sets that are there . Can anybody please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Check if the files exist before adding them in the loop:

```
%macro combine;
 data modelfit;
 set
     %do i = 30 %to 116 %by 3 ;
       %if %sysfunc(exist(stat&i)) %then %do ; stat&i %end ;
     %end;
        ;
 run;
%mend;
%combine;
```